Access Denied Error When Connecting ASP.NET Core Project to phpMyAdmin Live Server After MySQL Export/Import
I'm working on an ASP.NET Core project where I initially used a MySQL Workbench local database. I exported the entire database with data from MySQL Workbench and then imported it into phpMyAdmin on my live server. Now, I need to connect my ASP.NET Core application to the phpMyAdmin live server database.
I updated the connection string in my optionBuilder.UseMySql() method to the following:
optionsBuilder.UseMySql("server=localhost;port=3306;database=my_DB;user=username;password=password", Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ServerVersion.Parse("5.7.29-mysql"));

However, I am encountering an "Access Denied" error when trying to connect. The credentials (username and password) are correct, but I am still unable to establish the connection.
Could someone help me identify the cause of this issue and suggest a possible solution? Could it be related to server permissions or an incorrect server address?
Thanks in advance!

No, you did not import anything "into phpmyadmin" - phpmyadmin is just a GUI for database administration purposes. "Could it be related to server permissions or an incorrect server address?" - probably, but we can hardly tell you what would be correct, in your specific environment. Doesn't your hosting provider have documentation regarding this? Maybe your MySQL user is tied to a specific connection host name/address, 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost.

Does your asp.net app run on the same server as mysql?
